# (Rails) Plugin domain/scope issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, scope, dns

I'm having a bit of a domain/scope issue when it comes to some plugins.  Basically I'm using the OFC2 (http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart2/) for rails.  However, I already have a class in use called Charts.  I tried prepending a lot of my existing calls to Chart with "ActiveRecord::" but I'm not comfortable with this solution.  Is there a quality mechanism by which to change the OpenFlash items without breaking them?  Could I perhaps change its "Chart" to "Graph"?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull it in a Module, e.g.

```
Module Things
  class Charts
    #things
  end
end
```

and access it then e.g.

```
Things::Charts.new
```

Comment: Put which in a module?  My code, or theirs?  Both seem pretty well set, especially mine, given that it's an ActiveRecord class.  I actually ended up going through the OFC code and changed all references of CHART to GRAPH.  Everything *seems* to be working ok atm.

Comment: Since the plugin is hosted on github, perhaps you could fork it, put their code into a module (which helps everyone) and let them know so perhaps it makes it into a future version.

Comment: I think your code is better to put in a module - if the plugin chances, your work gets lost..?